# can vscode update import paths for files IMPORTING the moved files and not files being moved?

Tags: visual-studio-code

pretty much what the question says. If i move files I see files that were moved had their imports updated, but file referring to them don't. Also webpack aliases are in play as well.

Comment: that would be really useful!!!